# Find individual offset of all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a click function to align all selected elements on the right edge. Because using jQuery offset, I don't have access to offset.right, I need to do to some math.

I have some Javascript which finds the element with the greatest left offset, then finds the element with the greatest width. Then, I'm applying the greatest offset + the greatest width to all elements.

```
$('#align-right').click(function() {
  var x = $('.ui-selected')[0];
  $('.ui-selected').each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(this).offset().left > $(x).offset().left)
          x = el;
  });

  var highestOffset = $(x).offset().left;
  var biggestWidth = $(x).width();

  $('.ui-selected').css('left', highestOffset + biggestWidth);
});
```

However, I also need to subtract the width of each element from that offset. Each element can be a different width, so I can't use a set value.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6VagK/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the "right most" element by going over all elements and calculate right = left + width.

Once you have located the element, set the left of each element = right of right most element - width of each element.

```
$('#align-right').click(function () {
    var $that = $(".ui-selected:eq(0)");
    $(".ui-selected:gt(0)").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var thatRight = $that.offset().left + $that.width();
        var thisRight = $this.offset().left + $this.width();
        if (thisRight > thatRight) {
            $that = $this;
        }
    });
    $('.ui-selected').each(function () {
        var thatRight = $that.offset().left + $that.width();
        $(this).css({
            left: thatRight - $(this).width()
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6VagK/4/), feel free to drag and/or resize the elements.

Comment: That's aligning elements on the left edge. I've updated the fiddle with varied element widths, to make it more clear. http://jsfiddle.net/6VagK/2/

Comment: Turns out it was as simple as changing one x to y.